# PHP file is not receiving data from Angularjs, however data is present in array

Tags: php, angularjs

This is my php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "project");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "connection failed, restart server" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$total    = 0;
$recieved = 0;

$someJSON  = file_get_contents("php://input");
$someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
$id        = $someArray["id"];
$tranDate  = $someArray["tranDate"];
$tranId    = $someArray["tranId"];
$amount    = $someArray["amount"];
$gift      = $someArray["gift"];

if (!empty($id) && !empty($tranDate) && !empty($tranId) && !empty($amount) && !empty($gift)) {


    $sql = "INSERT INTO alltransectiondata (id, tranId, tranDate, gift, amount) " . "VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $tranId . "', '" . $tranDate . "', '" . $gift . "', '" . $amount . "');";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "failure";
    }
} else {
    echo "details are empty!!";
}
?>
```

This is angularjs code:

```
$scope.addTran = function(newData) {
    newData["id"] = $scope.currentId;
    console.log(newData); //this is showing full array no empty details
    sendData = angular.toJson(newData); //tried with converting to JSon, still not working
    console.log(angular.toJson(newData)); //this is also showing full array no empty details

    $http.post('php/addNewTransection.php', newData /*sendData*/ ).then(function(response, error) {
        console.log(angular.toJson(newData));
        console.log(response.data); //this shows []
        //$scope.indiData = response.data;
        //get();
    });

}
```

I am working with other PHP and angular code with same format and everything there problem is occurring with here only PHP receives null id, tranId etc, code not working with array and also not with json object.(tried both) in other files i am using angular.toJSon which works.
all naming and syntax are correct 3-4 times also I ran PHP file in browser it is correct with no errors,

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `.then(function(response){...}, function(error){...})` OR `.then(response, error)` (if they are already functions)

Comment: return value not to echo value

Comment: I deleted my answer as I think I had the wrong idea. I don't think there's enough information in what you are showing here to tell what is going wrong. Ideally you want to see the actual network request that has been made. You can do this, for example, in Chrome Developer Tools. I would then inspect each step of the process (verify what is inside the $someJSON variable, what is inside the $someArray variable etc) in order to identify where it is going wrong.

Comment: As a side note I notice you are using raw variable injection in your SQL query. in case you do not know it is very important you do not do this on any production code (and important enough that I never do it even in testing). Information here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: In your Angular code, you only append ``id`` to the object, nothing else? In that case, the PHP part would only receive eg. ``{"id": "someValue"}`` and go to the ``details are empty!`` else branch. The response is empty, probably because you haven't defined a content-type for the output of the PHP, eg. ``header('Content-Type: text/plain');`` in the beginning of the PHP file.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, thanks, but tried that still $id and others are getting null;

Comment: And I believe the Angular ``response`` requires a JSON, so you would need to return a JSON from the PHP side. So, set the header to: ``header('Content-Type: application/json');`` and build an object, eg. ``$response["data"] = "Hello there";``, and then return it: ``echo json_encode($response['data']);
return http_response_code(200);``

Comment: @JuhaUntinen, actually other data is coming from function part via foam in html, and in console i can see that data, all parameters are correct, problem is in php $id, $gift etc are getting null.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen, thanks ,will try return http_response_code, btw in my php angular files i am working with same format which all are working..

Comment: @mahipalsingh try a different syntax: `json_decode($someJSON);` and `$someArray->id;`

Comment: thanks @JuhaUntinen   , it works in format $http.post('php/somefile.php', {"id":$scope.currentId, "TranUniqueId": TranUniqueId})
but i will have to check that why it is working with direct json objects in other files. :D

Comment: @ChrisM, thanks for suggestion, i got it, actually we are making some offline data storage management, and ip will not be static, that is why raw variable are used here.